# JPanel not showing when added to another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I'm trying to create a game in Java - the game is going to be a 2-D scrolling game. I have a class called CornPanel which extends `JPanel` and shows a corn plant - the `CornPanel`'s are what will be moved across the screen. I know the `CornPanel` class is working because it shows up when I add it directly to a `JFrame`. However, when I try to add a `CornPanel` to another `JPanel` and then add that `JPanel` to the JFrame, the `CornPanel` doesn't show up.

Here's my `CornPanel` class (abbreviated - I took out the stuff I'm pretty sure isn't causing the problem):

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CornPanel extends JPanel{

    BufferedImage cornImage;

    public CornPanel(){
        loadImages();
    }

    public void loadImages(){
        try{
            cornImage = ImageIO.read(new File("src\\cornBasic.png"));
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(cornImage, 0, 0, cornImage.getWidth(), cornImage.getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

My Game class:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Game extends JFrame{

    ArrayList<CornPanel> cornPanels;
    JPanel gameContainer;

    public Game(){
        cornPanels = new ArrayList<CornPanel>();
        gameContainer = new JPanel();
        setSize(1000, 1000);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new Color(98, 249, 255));
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        getContentPane().add(gameContainer);

        addCornPanel();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addCornPanel(){

        CornPanel cornPanel = new CornPanel();
        cornPanels.add(cornPanel);
        gameContainer.add(cornPanel);
        cornPanel.setVisible(true); 
        getContentPane().repaint();
        repaint();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
    }
}
```

Note: I got it to work by setting the LayoutManager for both the `JFrame` and `gameContainer` to `new GridLayout(1,1)`, but the problem is that then I can't use `setLocation()` on the CornPanel in order to make it animate. If there's a way to do it without `setLocation()` let me know. Also, I took out a lot of code I don't think is necessary for diagnosing the problem - hopefully I didn't take out too much.

Comment: did you try using the revalidate() method after adding the cornPanel >?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your corn panel doesn't specify a prefered size, so the layout manager probably is just setting it to 0x0.

There is an easier way to add an icon into a pane.  [JLabel::JLabel(Icon)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#JLabel(javax.swing.Icon)) will create a label that has the image icon specified, and is of the right size to hold it.

If you do need something more complex than a single image, then your JComponent implementation should override getPreferredSize().

You also should call "pack" on your jframe, so that it can figure out the ideal size for display.

A few other comments not related to your original question:

1. You shouldn't extend JFrame for the main frame, just create a new JFrame instance, and configure it.
2. You should do the work in the Event Dispatch Thread. See [EventQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) and more specifically read through [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Thanks Mr. Thompson.  Good to see you around! I haven't been on cljp in a while.

Comment: comp.lang.java.programmer on usenet?  Heck I have not even heard it referred to in years.  ;)  Last I saw - 'Google Groups' had introduced so much spam that it was effectively dead.

Comment: Adding the getPreferredSize() fixed it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I know the `CornPanel` class is working because it shows up when I add it directly to a `JFrame`. However, when I try to add a `CornPanel` to another `JPanel` and then add that `JPanel` to the `JFrame`, the `CornPanel` doesn't show up.

The layout of the content pane of a frame is `BorderLayout`, the default constraint is `CENTER` which stretches a component to fill the space.

The default layout of a panel is `FlowLayout` which ..doesn't stretch the component to fit.

The best way to fix this is to (firstly) override the `getPreferredSize()` method of `CornPanel` to return a sensible size, then add it to a layout/constraint that has the behavior required when it has more space than it needs.